# Unable to run wxPython application in windows

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am not able to run wxPython application in windows7. I am getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ispace.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am able to run this application successfully in CentOS.
I also tried to google the fix for missing *core* module but could not find any interesting thing for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a bad installation of wxPython. Have you installed it using the official installation program from wxpython.org? Try re-installing, and make sure you have the right version for your operating system and python (32b/64b, same version of python).

What if you just run python on the command line and type in

```
import wx
```

Does it work?

Comment: You are right even import wx is not working. I have tried that as well...I have downloaded it from the official website twice..

Comment: Couldn't it be the case that you have 64bit windows, 32bit python and 64bit wxPython?